# How to fix button on top of a nested container in a form

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a search form. Users can use the side filters to narrow down their search, the search result appears on the right.

This is a simplified example, the real example has more filters. The problem is user needs to scroll the page to be able to hit the search button.

Is it possible to fix the search button on top of `filter-cn` so when user scroll down the page the search button still appears on top of the visible filter?

```css
.my-container {
  padding: 20px;
  
}

.filter-cn {
  padding: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
}

.fix-on-top {
  /* I want this button to appear on top of filter when user scrolls */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    </nav>

    <div class="container my-container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4  filter-cn">
          <form>
            <div class="fix-on-top">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Search</button>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Keyword</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="keyword" placeholder="Looking for...">

              <label>Make</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="Make" placeholder="Make...">

              <label>Model</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="Model" placeholder="model...">
            </div>

          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-8">
          second colum for displaying search result on the side
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

I want to see something like this when user scrolls down:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`position: sticky` may be what you need.

Demo:

```css
.my-container {
  padding: 20px;
  
}

.filter-cn {
  padding: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
}

.fix-on-top {
  /* I want this button to appear on top of filter when user scrolls */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    </nav>

    <div class="container my-container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4  filter-cn">
          <form>
            <div class="fix-on-top">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Search</button>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Keyword</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="keyword" placeholder="Looking for...">

              <label>Make</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="Make" placeholder="Make...">

              <label>Model</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="Model" placeholder="model...">
            </div>

          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-8">
          second colum for displaying search result on the side
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuong has it - you need a position property that tells it to stay ontop.

```
.fix-on-top {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
}
```

Both fixed and sticky should work really.